# Feather icons with Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm a Bootstrap 4 beginner. What is the best way to use the [Feather icons](https://feathericons.com/) with Bootstrap 4?

Comment: The first step is to check the documentation. The second step is to produce some code and if it doesn't work, then post a valid question.

Comment: Show the code/what you have tried so far. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can install this

`npm install feather-icons`

or

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons/dist/feather.min.js"></script>
  <body>

    <!-- example icon -->
    <i data-feather="circle"></i>

    <script>
      feather.replace()
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

learn more details about it
 https://github.com/colebemis/feather#quick-start

Answer (score 0):

Try react-feather
https://github.com/feathericons/react-feather

Installation

```
yarn add react-feather
```

or

```
npm i react-feather
```

Usage

```
import React from 'react';
import { Camera } from 'react-feather';

const App = () => {
  return <Camera />
};

export default App;
```